# About directly finding the PDF vs finding the PDF from a CDF

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Lets consider a simple question : Say $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables which are sampling uniformly from $[0,1]$. We want to compute the PDF of $XY$.

The typical approach seems to be to compute,  $F_{XY}(a) = P[XY \leq a] = 1 - P[XY  \geq a] = 1 - \int _{y=a}^1 \int_{x=a/y}^1 \, dx \, dy = a - a\ln(a)$ And then by differentiation it follows that $f_{XY}(a) = -\ln(a)$

- What looks a bit weird to me is that the above method looks almost unique to me. As in I can't imagine any way to say get the $f_{XY}(a)$ directly or to say compute $P[XY \leq a]$ instead of going through $P[XY  \geq a]$.
- Is it typically not possible to compute pdfs directly when dealing with continuous random variables?

Comment: The PDF-CDF-CDF-PDF route is indeed a détour and can quite often be replaced by a direct PDF-PDF route. In your case, note that for every measurable bounded $u$, $$E(u(XY))=\iint_{[0,1]^2}u(xy)dxdy,$$ and the change of variable $z=xy$, $t=x$, yields $dzdt=tdxdy$ and $0<z<t<1$ hence $$E(u(XY))=\int_0^1u(z)\left(\int_z^1\frac{dt}t\right)dz$$ from which the density $f_{XY}$ arises as the parenthesis, that is, $$f_Z(z)=\mathbf 1_{0<z<1}\int_z^1\frac{dt}t=-\log z\,\mathbf 1_{0<z<1}.$$

Comment: Thanks for this new perspective. But is there a way to understand why we can't compute $P[XY < a ]$ directly?

Comment: But we can compute $P(XY<a)$ directly, whatever "directly" means: for every $a$ in $(0,1)$, $$P(XY<a)=\iint_{[0,1]^2}\mathbf 1_{xy<a}dxdy=\int_0^1\int_0^{\min(1,a/y)}dxdy=\int_0^1\min(1,a/y)dy$$ hence $$P(XY<a)=\int_0^ady+\int_a^1(a/y)dy=a-a\log a.$$